# 401 Unauthorized when making a request to dataverse web api

Tags: node.js, msal.js, dataverse

I am new to dynamics 365 and even newer to the Dataverse Web API. I am trying to create a s2s application in nodejs that will just update a contact on a trigger. I have registered my app in AAD and created a new Application User. I am able to get an access token but when I use the token to make a simple request to the Dataverse Web API I am getting a 401 status code.

````
import msal from '@azure/msal-node';
import { response } from 'express';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "<clientID>",
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>",
        clientSecret: '<clientSecret>'
    }
}

const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

const tokenRequest = {
    scopes: ["https://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/.default"]
};

const resp = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(tokenRequest).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.accessToken);
});

async function makeRequest(accessToken) {
    const url = 'http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/accounts?$select=name&$top=3';
    var obj = { 
                method: 'GET', 
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset-utf-8',
                    'OData-MaxVersion': '4.0',
                    'OData-Version': '4.0',
                    'If-None-Match': null
                }
            };
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url, obj);
                console.log('response.status: ', response.status);
            } catch(err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
}

makeRequest(response.accessToken);
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing:

```
http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.2/accounts?$select=name&$top=3';
```

To:

```
http://myorg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/accounts?$select=name&$top=3';
```

going back a version of the web api allowed me access.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Mr will i had the same problem and i solve it by changing the auth URL

Instead of:

```
"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>"
```

Try:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token
```

Comment: I am getting an untrust_authority error when I include that.